# bytearray throwing error for python class object when ctype structure present as class attributes

Tags: python, ctypes

I was able to convert ctype class object into `bytearray()` using below method -

```
from ctypes import *

class get_log_input_payload(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = (
        ("log_identifier",c_uint8*16),
        ("offset",c_uint32),
        ("length",c_uint32)
    )
payload = get_log_input_payload()
b_array = bytearray(payload)
```

but when we used ctype class as an attributes inside python class, `bytearray()` started throwing error "**TypeError: cannot convert '_ctypes.PyCStructType' object to bytearray**"

```
from ctypes import *

class Mailbox:
    get_log_input_payload = type("get_log_input_payload", (Structure, ), {"_fields_" : [("log_identifier",c_uint8*16),
                                                                                        ("offset",c_uint32),
                                                                                        ("length",c_uint32)]})

obj = Mailbox()
payload = obj.get_log_input_payload 
b_array = bytearray(payload) # <--- Throwing error
```

Note:
Updated typo in the code

Comment: `Structure`, `c_uint32`,`c_uint8` are not defined. So cannot replicate the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: u can import it 

from ctypes import *
from struct import *

Comment: updated code, please check now.

Comment: the error is not where you pointed to in the question. The error is with this line of code: `get_log_input_payload`.  TypeError: string indices must be integers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are making a class manually with `type`, but there are two errors in the provided code.  There is a missing colon(:) in the `type` call after the `_fields_` key, and then the type must be instantiated:

```py
from ctypes import *

class Mailbox:
    get_log_input_payload = type("get_log_input_payload", (Structure, ), {"_fields_": [("log_identifier",c_uint8*16),
#                                                                     missing colon ^                                                                                        ("offset",c_uint32),
                                                                                        ("length",c_uint32)]})

obj = Mailbox()
payload = obj.get_log_input_payload()  # missing () to instantiate the type
b_array = bytearray(payload)
print(b_array)
```

Output:

```
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

Comment: Thanks lot for your suggestion ! I have added extra __init__ function in class which creates object of get_log_input_payload, so every time I create Mailbox object I need not manually create get_log_input_payload  object.